# React Native Android WebView: javaScriptEnabled does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, android, webview, react-native

While developing an app with React Native for Android, I was attempting to use a WebView for an OAuth flow. The WebView displayed correctly, but the provider redirected to their "JavaScript must be enabled" error page.

I thought I found a quick and clear answer in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content) quoted below, but after setting this property, I still got redirected to the provider's "JavaScript must be enabled" error page.

> android javaScriptEnabled bool
>   Used on Android only, JS is enabled by default for WebView on iOS

I created the following component as a reduction, and sure enough, when the WebView displays the resulting page, it reports that JavaScript is not enabled.

Am I overlooking something?

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  WebView,
} = React;

var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      url: 'https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled',
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return(
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <WebView style={styles.webview}
          url={this.state.url}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  },

});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are referencing pre-release version 0.18 which contains a breaking change regarding enabling JavaScript in Android WebView.

> Breaking changes
>
> To enable JavaScript in Android WebView, use javaScriptEnabled instead
>   of javaScriptEnabledAndroid.

[react-native 0.18](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.18.0-rc)

If you are on a version under 0.18 you can use `javaScriptEnabledAndroid` but be aware that this will break once it is officially released.